# htaccess rewrite all using http:// or http://www. to https except for one or two URI

Tags: .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, https

**What I am currently using is:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**What I actually want is:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [AND]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/folder/next_folder/(custom_id)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

As you can see I am trying to add an extra conditions before rewriting to https.
For all pages I used https but now firefox has an update and gives problems with Mixed content (when loading iframe that uses http:// instead of https://):

https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2013/05/16/mixed-content-blocking-in-firefox-aurora/

That's why I need to exclude a few pages from using https:// notice I remove the www. too.

I tried different things but still getting errors or it just does not work like it supposed to do. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the rewrite condition to the part where `http:` is ON not where `https:` is already ON.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/next_folder/custom_id
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This did the trick. I changed !-on to !=off and https to http so they are forced to view it via http (suits me better). I also added another condition with [OR] below the first one. Everything works now.Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @RensTillmann Glad you got it working just the way you wanted! :)